# How to stop PubNub iOS SDK to log on Xcode console

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, pubnub

Currently I am working with the PubNub iOS SDK for implementing Chat/ Messaging functionality in an application. Anyway it it too much annoying to have a large amount of log messages from PubNub SDK on my Xcode console like

```
PNLog: Current console dump file size is 486754 bytes (maximum allowed: 10485760 bytes)
2015-04-20 14:19:10.351 Qrosity[3966:60554] PubNub (0x1034049a0) 

+--------------------------------------------------------------
| +--------+          +-+       +-+     +-+          +-+
| | +----+ |          | |       |  \    | |          | |
| | |    | |          | |       | \ \   | |          | |
| | +----+ | +-+  +-+ | +-----\ | |\ \  | | +-+  +-+ | +-----\
| | +------+ | |  | | | +---+ | | | \ \ | | | |  | | | +---+ |
| | |        | |  | | | |   | | | |  \ \| | | |  | | | |   | |
| | |        | +--+ | | +---+ | | |   \   | | +--+ | | +---+ |
| +-+        \------/ +-------/ +-+    \--+ \------/ +-------/
|
|
| PubNub.com real-time messaging network information:
| - version: 3.7.10.3
| - git branch: master
| - commit identifier: d0367a4932299d49aba45c82876b342999cad294
+--------------------------------------------------------------

2015-04-20 14:19:10.385 Qrosity[3966:60714] PubNub (0x7fbd0480fad0) TRY UPDATE CONFIGURATION (STATE: 'created')
2015-04-20 14:19:10.385 Qrosity[3966:60554] PubNub (0x7fbd0480fad0) INSTANCE USE OBSERVER INSTANCE AT 0x7fbd04811730, REACHABILITY INSTANCE AT 0x7fbd04819c00, CRYPTO HELPER INSTANCE AT <null>, MESSAGING CHANNEL INSTANCE AT <null>, SERVICE CHANNEL INSTANCE AT <null> 
2015-04-20 14:19:10.385 Qrosity[3966:60714] PubNub (0x7fbd0480fad0) VALID CONFIGURATION HAS BEEN PROVIDED (STATE: 'created')
2015-04-20 14:19:10.386 Qrosity[3966:60714] PubNub (0x7fbd0480fad0) CONFIGURATION CAN BE APPLIED W/O RECONNECTION (STATE: 'created')
2015-04-20 14:19:10.387 Qrosity[3966:60714] PubNub (0x7fbd0480fad0) 

+-------------------------------------------------------------
| PubNub configuration information:
| - origin: pubsub.pubnub.com
| - publish key: pub*****ec9
| - subscribe key: sub*****a4f
| - secret key: sec*****zcx
| - cipher key: not specified
| - subscribe request timeout: 10
| - non-subscribe request timeout: 10
| - should auto-reconnect: 1
| - should keep time token on channels list change: 1
| - should resubscribe on connection restore: 1
| - should restore subscription with last time token: 1
| - should use secure connection: 1
| - able to reduce security level on error: 1
| - able to use insecure connection: 1
| - should accept compressed responses: 1
| - presence heartbeat timeout: 0
| - presence heartbeat interval: 2
+--------------------------------------------------------------
```

or like these

```
2015-04-20 14:27:15.398 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier::WRITE] SCHEDULING OPENING... (STATE: 25194624)
2015-04-20 14:27:15.398 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier::WRITE] OPEN IS SCHEDULED (STATE: 25227392)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.338 Qrosity[4068:64597] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier::READ] STREAM OPENED (STREAM IS OPENED)(STATE: 25227392)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.339 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNConnection (0x7f84b3f0d650) [CONNECTION::PNServiceConnectionIdentifier::READ] STREAM OPENED (STREAM IS OPENED)(STATE: 25227392)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.339 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNConnection (0x7f84b3f0d650) [CONNECTION::PNServiceConnectionIdentifier] HANDLE STREAM CONNECTION OPENED (STATE: 16904320)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.340 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNConnection (0x7f84b3f0d650) [CONNECTION::PNServiceConnectionIdentifier::WRITE] STREAM OPENED (STREAM IS OPENED) (STATE: 16904320)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.339 Qrosity[4068:64597] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier] HANDLE STREAM CONNECTION OPENED (STATE: 16904320)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.340 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNConnection (0x7f84b3f0d650) [CONNECTION::PNServiceConnectionIdentifier] HANDLE STREAM CONNECTION OPENED (STATE: 258176)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.341 Qrosity[4068:64597] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier::WRITE] STREAM OPENED (STREAM IS OPENED) (STATE: 16904320)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.342 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNConnection (0x7f84b3f0d650) [CONNECTION::PNServiceConnectionIdentifier] CONNECTED (BY USER REQUEST? 1) (STATE: 258048)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.342 Qrosity[4068:64597] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier] HANDLE STREAM CONNECTION OPENED (STATE: 258176)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.343 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNServiceChannel (0x7f84b3d26490) [CHANNEL::PNServiceConnectionIdentifier] HANDLE CONNECTION EVENT (STATE: 129)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.343 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNServiceChannel (0x7f84b3d26490) [CHANNEL::PNServiceConnectionIdentifier] CONNECTED (STATE: 8)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.343 Qrosity[4068:64597] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier] CONNECTED (BY USER REQUEST? 1) (STATE: 258048)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.343 Qrosity[4068:64618] PubNub (0x7f84b6001ae0) CHANNEL CONNECTED: PNServiceConnectionIdentifier (0x7f84b3d26490) (STATE: 'connecting')
2015-04-20 14:27:17.344 Qrosity[4068:64595] PNMessagingChannel (0x7f84b3d380b0) [CHANNEL::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier] HANDLE CONNECTION EVENT (STATE: 129)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.344 Qrosity[4068:64595] PNMessagingChannel (0x7f84b3d380b0) [CHANNEL::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier] CONNECTED (STATE: 8)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.344 Qrosity[4068:64595] PubNub (0x7f84b6001ae0) CHANNEL CONNECTED: PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier (0x7f84b3d380b0) (STATE: 'connecting')
2015-04-20 14:27:17.345 Qrosity[4068:64597] PubNub (0x7f84b6001ae0) BOTH CHANNELS CONNECTED TO THE ORIGIN: pubsub.pubnub.com (STATE: 'connecting')
2015-04-20 14:27:17.346 Qrosity[4068:64597] PubNub (0x7f84b6001ae0) CONNECTED TO: pubsub.pubnub.com (STATE: 'connected')
2015-04-20 14:27:17.347 Qrosity[4068:64597] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier::WRITE] NOTHING TO WRITE (STATE: 67366912)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.404 Qrosity[4068:64020] PubNubChatManager: CONNECTED TO SERVER WITH ORIGIN: pubsub.pubnub.com
2015-04-20 14:27:17.441 Qrosity[4068:64595] PNConnection (0x7f84b3f0d650) [CONNECTION::PNServiceConnectionIdentifier::WRITE] NOTHING TO WRITE (STATE: 67366912)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.590 Qrosity[4068:64618] PubNub (0x7f84b6001ae0) TRYING TO SUBSCRIBE ON CHANNELS: (
    "PNChannel(0x7f84b6361850) ChIJLZ9vmE10AjoR2ftJs2B-Plw"
) (SHOULD CATCH UP? 0) (STATE: 'connected')
2015-04-20 14:27:17.591 Qrosity[4068:64618] PubNub (0x7f84b6001ae0) SUBSCRIBE ON CHANNELS (STATE: 'connected')
2015-04-20 14:27:17.612 Qrosity[4068:64618] PNMessagingChannel (0x7f84b3d380b0) [CHANNEL::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier] SUBSCRIBING ON SPECIFIC SET OF CHANNELS... (STATE: 0)
2015-04-20 14:27:17.648 Qrosity[4068:64618] PubNub (0x7f84b6001ae0) WILL SUBSCRIBE ON CHANNELS: (
    "PNChannel(0x7f84b6361850) ChIJLZ9vmE10AjoR2ftJs2B-Plw"
) (STATE: 'connected')
2015-04-20 14:27:17.648 Qrosity[4068:64739] PNConnection (0x7f84b3cc7210) [CONNECTION::PNMessagingConnectionIdentifier::WRITE] NOTHING TO WRITE (STATE: 67366912)
```

There are useful console logs from my application to test it's functionality. It is very difficult to find them due to a large amount of PubNub SDK console. IS there any way to stop the sdk from logging such messages? I found an unanswered question at PubNub community [here](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/211/how-do-i-enable-and-disable-logging-in-ios-sdk).

Answer (score 1):

Oh! I just missed the answer. Go to `PNMacro.h` and change the macro values from 1 to 0.

```
#define PNLOG_GENERAL_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_REACHABILITY_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_DESERIALIZER_INFO_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_DESERIALIZER_ERROR_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL_LAYER_ERROR_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL_LAYER_INFO_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_COMMUNICATION_CHANNEL_LAYER_WARN_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_CONNECTION_LAYER_ERROR_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_CONNECTION_LAYER_INFO_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_CONNECTION_LAYER_RAW_HTTP_RESPONSE_LOGGING_ENABLED 0
#define PNLOG_CONNECTION_LAYER_RAW_HTTP_RESPONSE_STORING_ENABLED 0
```

**It will stop all the logging.** That's it.

Comment: You probably should leave the `*_ERROR_LOGGING_ENABLED 1` ignoring errors is not a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sauvik,

There is few places where you can disable logging and all of them described in this section https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c#logging (mentioned in community as well).
There is a way to disable logging with macro or using bitfield with `+enableFor:/+disableFor:` to enable disable particular logging level.
You can also use `+loggerEnabled:` with `NO` to disable output to console and `+dumpToFile:` with `NO` to disable log storing in dump file (if you want).